# how add a jquery plugin to webpack in a jhipster project

Tags: angular, jquery-plugins, jhipster, webpack-3

I can not add a jquery library to my jhipster project, I think it's specific to webpack,

here is an exemple with fullcalendar, but i have the same probleme with all jquery plugin

all is in src/main/webapp/app/layouts/main/main.component.ts & webpack/webpack.common.js

if i try this:

main.component.ts

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'fullcalendar';
```

webpack.common.js

```
module: {
rules: [
{ test: /fullcalendar\/dist\/.+\.js/, loader: 'imports-loader?$=jquery' },
{ test: /bootstrap\/dist\/js\/umd\//, loader: 'imports-loader?jQuery=jquery' },
```

....
i got an error with:  ERROR TypeError: jquery_1.default is not a function

if i try like the exemple on fullcalendar doc:

```
module: {
rules: [
{ test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader' },
{ enforce: 'pre', test: /\.js$/, loader: 'source-map-loader' },
```

i got error like :

[at-loader] ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts:18:5 
    TS2539: Cannot assign to 'FullcalendarExempleAppModule' because it is not a variable.

[at-loader] ./src/main/webapp/app/layouts/main/main.component.ts:9:95 
    TS2339: Property 'metadata' does not exist on type 'typeof Reflect'.

[at-loader] ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts:18:5 
    TS2539: Cannot assign to 'FullcalendarExempleAppModule' because it is not a variable.

jquery_1.default is not a function

I tried other tips for hours, but none works ...
i dont understand why add a simple jquery plugin seems so hard

i put a jhipster project exemple on github (because i dont know how make a jsfiddle of this project ...) :

https://github.com/brynnlow/jhipster-fullcalendar-exemple.git

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting your question, you want to add a jQuery plugin in your jhpster project.

I would suggest you to add all your JS files/ Modules in vendor.ts file by using import command.

```
import 'path_to_file/file_name.js';
```

Similarly all CSS related files should be imported to vendor.css or vendor.scss.

You need to make a build of your project by

```
yarn run webpack:build
```

once you are making any changes to your vendor.ts file.

Comment: add this to my vendor.ts

import * as moment from 'moment';
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
import '../../../../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js';

and remove from main.component.ts

but i keep ERROR TypeError: jQuery(...).fullCalendar is not a function

Comment: In your main.component.ts, no need to import jquery.
In place of this: import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
write 
declare var $: any;

then replace your jQuery variable to $. I think this might resolve your issue.

Comment: my vendor.ts is now : import * as moment from 'moment';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'fullcalendar';

and my main.component.ts: declare var $: any; 

but still TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function, i update the github exemple

Comment: I think, the problem is in the import. Maybe this can help.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51213980/8436194